# How do I create a file in node?

Tags: javascript, file, node.js

I want to take some data, in this case an XML, and create a feed.rss file and place it in /public. What would I use to do this?

If the file already exists there I want to overwrite it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation on the node.js [filesystem (fs) API](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/fs.html).

Specifically, I believe [fs.writeFile()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/fs.html#fs.writeFile) will be your API call of choice.